# looking for procedure instead of trigger which we can schedule as a job

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

Instead of trigger i am planning to write a procedure which we can run using job which will work same way as TRIGGER
with these two tables in the same way.
how can i do that?

here are my tables with column names

```
1.tblcal

ID(int,not null)
UID(varchar(10),null)
Desc(varchar(200),null)
Date(datetime,null)
avbl(varchar(5),null)

2.tblEvent
ID(int,notnull)
UID(varchar(10),null)
Desc(varchar(200),null)
Date(datetime,null)
```

Down is my trigger on tblEvent..

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trU] ON [dbo].[tblEvent] 
FOR INSERT
AS
Declare @CuID char(6),

@CuDesc char(40),
@CuDate datetime 

SET NOCOUNT ON

Select @CuID = i.UID , @CuDesc=i.Desc, @CuDate=i.Date From Inserted i

If(@CuDesc !='available')
Begin
Update tblCal set avbl='Out', Desc=@CurDesc where cadate=@CuDate and UID=@CuID
ENd

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

I have another problem with Desc column.Desc which are going to be in and out Basically we need to update tblcal differently for different descriptions;in that case I don't think trigger is that reliable;Means for example for 10 Desc we need to update in and for other 10 we need to update out

Actually every thursday on the tblevent data is loaded once its loaded it fired a trigger and will update in tblcal.

but my client is looking for a procedure which we can schedule as a job after the tblevent entry done on Thursday.

How can i do with stored procedure?

Comment: Oh boy, your trigger is already problematic, did you know that `INSERT ... VALUES(1),(2),(3);` will fail, since the trigger will only handle one of the rows?

Answer (score 0):

### Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_UpdateEventData
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE C 
     SET c.avbl   = 'Out'
        ,c.[Desc] = e.[Desc]
    FROM [dbo].tblCal C 
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tblEvent] e ON c.[UID]  = e.[UID]
                                 AND c.cadate = e.[Date]  --<-- check if you only want
    WHERE e.[Desc] <> 'available'                         -- to join on date not datetime
END                                                       -- CAST both columns to DATE
```

Also if you are keeping your Trigger as it is you will need to modify the trigger definition to handle multiple Inserts, You can use the same logic as in this procedure to update your trigger definition.

### Trigger Fix

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trU] ON [dbo].[tblEvent] 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE C 
     SET c.avbl   = 'Out'
        ,c.[Desc] = i.[Desc]
    FROM [dbo].tblCal C 
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON c.[UID]  = i.[UID]
                                 AND c.cadate = i.[Date]
    WHERE i.[Desc] <> 'available'


END
```

Comment: HI Ali, So you are asking to do cast on both the date columns if we are joining on datetime like this.. ( convert(varchar, t1.CalDate, 111) as Date) the date column in both the tables will show as 2014-10-01 00:00:00.000.how can i do cast here?

Comment: And also in the trigger is After insert or for insert?

Comment: I meant to say, if you do not care about the time and you only want to join on DATE you can write it something like `CAST(c.cadate AS DATE) = CAST(e.[Date] AS DATE)`  .  Also I have fixed the trigger just incase if you want to keep the trigger. Both procedure and trigger should work.

Comment: thank you but in trigger do we need to place for insert or after insert?

Comment: Either should work fine, `AFTER INSERT` or `FOR INSERT` both will create an after insert trigger.

Comment: Do you have any idea why my exisitng trigger didnt worked?it worked last till last week suddenly it stopped why...

Comment: You existing trigger will only work for a single insert, but will fail for multiple inserts, if you insert 10 rows with one sql statement , the trigger only fire once, now in this case you will have 10 rows in your inserted table and when you try to assign values to variables CuID, CuDesc and CuDate , your select returns multiple values hence it errors out and trigger fails.

Comment: but before that also it was doing the same job not sure exactly why its stopped ...is this is the reason which you mentioned...